# Puxar dados do DataGridView para um formulário

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Estou com um problema onde tenho dois Forms `TelaInicio` e `ExibirDados` e estou tentando fazer com que quando o usuário der um double click em alguma linha no Grid abrirá um formulário puxando as informações referente aquela linha.

Primeiro estou instanciando o formulário `ExibirDados` em `TelaInicio`

```
 public partial class TelaInicio : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
 {

    internal ExibirDados exibirdados = null;

    public TelaInicio(ExibirDados exibirdados)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.exibirdados = exibirdados;
    }
```

E ao dar Double Click no Grid executo esse código:

```
  private void dgvDados_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  {
        if (dgvDados.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.exibirdados.txtcnpj.Text = dgvDados.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.dtpcadastro.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtrazao.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.cmboperadora.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtlinhas.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.cmbClassificacao.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.dtpvigencia.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtcontrato.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.cmbFidelidade.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtvalorgasto.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtfixoempresa.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtgestor.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtcelular.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtfixogestor.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtemail.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtobs.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
        }

        ExibirDados form = new ExibirDados();
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Com esse código ele até abre o form mas não puxa nenhuma informação para os campos, a quantidade de campos está certa e no meu caso a chave primária é o CNPJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está atribuindo os valores ao form `this.exibirdados`, mas está instanciando um novo `ExibirDados` e exibindo este recém criado.

Troque isso:

```
ExibirDados form = new ExibirDados();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Por isso:

```
this.exibirdados.ShowDialog();
```